# Data Errors on Bits or Blocks

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, backup, hardware-failure, storage

I am storing data on HDDs and SSDs and I'm worried about data corruption. Does the data ever have single bit errors, or is it always entire blocks that do not read correctly? I believe there is some kind of error correction on disk controllers, so I'm not sure how single bit errors can occur.

Comment: Single bit errors occur all the time on both magnetic and SSD media. they can be cause by cosmic rays hitting a cell, or by a weakening of the magnetic media in a small area of an HDDs platter, or by countless other causes. RAM occasionally emits alpha-particles that can corrupt data to be written while it sits in memory, or on the SSD if its close enough. all the answers below are related to the many layers of attempts to address these issues of physics. see bitrot for more details. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_degradation

Comment: Yes, there are single bit errors.

Answer (score 3):

The answer your looking for is ECC or error correction.  Each sector on every storage device has built in ECC data.  This data is used to correct single bit and even multi-bit errors.  It has limits, and once those limits are exceed the whole sector is deemed losts.

You can verify this but using a program that will give you access to SMART like smartctl -a /dev/sda.  It will printout a whole screen full of data but there will be a couple entries specifically for ECC.  When the drive is new ECC corrected sectors will be 0, and when its near the end of its life it will go into the hundreds of millions or even billions.  It may even roll over to 0 and start over.

If you have 100's of millions of ECC per day replace the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Data *does* get corrupted on HDD, and more so on [SSD on power fault](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-ssd-power-faults-scramble-your-data/). JEDEC specifies that an [SSD need retain data only for one year without power](https://www.minitool.com/partition-disk/what-happens-to-data-on-ssd-when-power-is-lost.html). The cause of corruption can be improper shutdown, a microscopic speck of dust on a platter, charge leakage in an SSD, a cosmic ray flipping a single bit, etc. Failures can be to a single bit or to a region on disk. Disk checking programs can spot *any* error and try to rewrite and reread data. [A soft error can be fixed by overwriting; a hard error is a permanently damaged block](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/hard-vs-soft-bad-sectors-hdd-different-causes-solutions/).

The safest approach is to store *multiple copies* with a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) or [cyclic redundancy check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). The space shuttle used **five** redundant computers because of mission criticality and higher rate of radiation above shielding atmosphere.

For archival storage,

- Choose media that lasts a long time without power. The best available now might be the [sapphire disk](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/132793-the-10-million-year-sapphire-hard-disk). HDD and SSD might have similar failure rates in use, but HDD being is reliable without power, and SSD more reliable in mechanically abusive situation, as long as it has power.
- Use a checksum to check file integrity. If you archive data, [zip contains a built-in checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688729/checksums-on-zip-files#_=_) to verify the file is valid. If a single bit or more has been corrupted, on trying to open the zip file, an alert is issued.
- Store data redundantly in multiple environments. Put the most essential data in the cloud *and* on multiple drives locally. If one zip archive flags some data as damaged, another copy should be good. Consider the statistics of failure: if a single file has odds of one in a million of failing (10<sup>-6</sup>), the odds that two *separately-stored* copies would *both* be bad is 10<sup>-6</sup> * 10<sup>-6</sup>, i.e., one in a trillion (10<sup>-12</sup>). Of course, if files are stored in the same location and a disaster destroys the building, the data is gone.
- Most important, **verify** that stored data is readable. A company for which I worked assiduously made tape backups, only to find, on the day one was needed, *none* of the backups were readable.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t agree more with cybernard.

But if you are worry about the data integrity, a modern file system like ZFS or Btrfs which support redondancy on multiple disk, checksums and a scrubing process is a must. (Modern is a relative term, ZFS was introduced in 2005).